# Change color in file modercvcolorgreen.sty

Tags: moderncv

How can I change the color of the title of the sections and bars? I tried modifying the file `moderncvcolorgreen.sty`, in the line

```
\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0,0,0}% black
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0,100,0}%Mygreen
%\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.35,0.70,0.30}% green
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0.45,0.45,0.45}% dark grey
```

but the result is not the desired:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which style do you use? Can you please show us a short **compilable** code **without** personal informations?

Comment: When using `rgb` option in `\definecolor` command, the numbers has to be between 0 and 1... there are other ways too like RGB that can accept 0-255. Check here for more: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not to change file `moderncvcolorgreen.sty`, you can simply add new definitions for the color(s) in your preamble.

To define the colors of bars and section title you need to change color `color1` like

```
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{100,0,0} % Mygreen defined as red
```

To make the change easy visuable I used here color red in RGB color model.  See `texdoc xcolor` for more informations ...

The definition of `color1` is not only used in the section as you can see in the following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual} % casual, classic, banking, oldstyle and fancy
\moderncvcolor{green}  % <=============================================

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}
\quote{Some quote}

\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{100,0,0}%Mygreen defined as red <=============


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description 
  no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description 
  line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{\textbf{Language} 2}{\textbf{Skill} level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}

\end{document}
```

and its resulting first page:

[image]

If you **only** want to change the color of bars and section text you have to redefine the command `\section` like

```
\makeatletter
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{100,0,0} % My color for bar and section
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sm}{%
  \par\addvspace{2.5ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}%
  \parbox[t]{\hintscolumnwidth}{\strut\raggedleft\raisebox{\baseletterheight}{\color{mycolor}\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.95ex}}}%
  \hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
  \parbox[t]{\maincolumnwidth}{\strut\sectionstyle{#2}}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}\@afterheading}% to avoid a pagebreak after the heading

\renewcommand*{\sectionstyle}[1]{{\sectionfont\textcolor{mycolor}{#1}}}
\makeatother
```

and add this code in your preamble.

Comment: Is my comment above wrong? (rgb options that have to be between 0 and 1)

Comment: @koleygr In the manual is written, that `rgb` accepts `0..1`, but it also recognizes the range `0..255` (as it is done by `RGB`) ...

Comment: Thanks... I thought RGB was for this reason instead. (To be honest seems strange to me (and I will check it soon) because lets suppose I want to define \definecolor{nottoored}{rgb}{1,0,0} to be 1 of 255 and not 1 of 1... how can the compiler understand what I mean?)

Comment: Although there's no point specifying `100,0,0` in that case, just write `1,0,0` to avoid possible user confusion. E.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586350/xcolor-specifying-color-in-rgb-or-cymk-does-not-work-correctly